# Yii2 Gridview filtering a column that has Int data type based on varchar as inputed value

Tags: php, search, gridview, filter, yii2

I've an gridView for showing data. GridView table has a column that called as **Created By**, this column contain the **ID** of **User** that I get from **user table**. Basicly, this column will show data as Integer(ID) like this:

[image]

But I've set code like this to show the *username* of the *ID*:

```
[
  'attribute' => 'created_by',
  'format' => 'raw',
  'value' => function ($data) {
                $modelUser = Users::find()->where(['id' => $data->created_by])->one();
                $nama = $modelUser->username;
                return $nama;
            },
  'vAlign' => 'middle',
  'hAlign' => 'center',
],
```

**Result**:

[image]

The gridView has filter column, I'm trying to filter data based on inserted value. I'm trying input username as the value for filtering but it give an error message "**created By must be an Integer**", like this:

[image]

#### How do I can filtering that column using the a username(varchar)?

Thanks

### Update

This is my **searchModel.php**

```
<?php

 namespace app\search;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Model;
 use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
 use app\models\Product;

 /**
 * ProductSearch represents the model behind the search form of `app\models\Product`.
 */
class ProductSearch extends Product {

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['productId', 'userId', 'parentId', 'created_by'], 'integer'],
        [['date', 'created_at', 'name', 'address'], 'safe'],
        [['price'], 'number'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios() {
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params) {
    $query = Product::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'productId' => $this->productId,
        'price' => $this->price,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['MONTH(date)' => $this->date])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $this->address]);

    return $dataProvider;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
       [['productId', 'userId', 'parentId'], 'integer'],
       [['date', 'created_at', 'name', 'address'], 'safe'],
       [['price'], 'number'],
       [['created_by'], 'string'],
   ];
}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Product::find()->joinWith('createdBy'); // Whatever relation name
.
.
.
.
.
   // grid filtering conditions
   $query->andFilterWhere([
      'productId' => $this->productId,
      'price' => $this->price,
      'created_at' => $this->created_at,
   ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['MONTH(date)' => $this->date])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $this->address])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'userTableName.username', $this->created_by]); // Whatever table name and field name.


    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: It's work, but I have to create model relational first. Because both of my table don't have relational to each other.Thanks :D

Comment: But, how do I can make it work if I have another column, for example column **email**. That column email based on user ID, just like the Created By. I've try to use the same relational, or just use the preview relational. But it didn't work wekll.

Comment: @Blackjack. You wan to filter user by email or username both? Explain.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a proper filter to your column

```
[
    'attribute'=>'your_attribute',
     ......
     'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(YourModel::find()->asArray()->all(), 
                   'your_id_column', 'your_name_column'),
],
```